# Parse JSON object from Ajax response

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am using Ajax to retrieve a response from an external API.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".nd-tracking").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "nd-request.php", 
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "<pre>" + data["json"] + "</pre>"
        );

        var obj = data["json"];
        for (var key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="nd-request.php" method="post" class="nd-tracking">
    Consignment ID: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Consignment ID" name="consignmentid"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<div class="the-return">

</div>
```

My returned data is an object

```
[
{"code":{"0":"BKD"},"date":{"0":"2016-06-30"},"time":{"0":"08:51:33"},"trackEvent":{"0":"Magda Sliwa"}},
{"code":{"0":"ACC"},"date":{"0":"2016-06-30"},"time":{"0":"11:59:43"},"trackEvent":{"0":"Depot"},"carrierEvent":"accepted"},
{"code":{"0":"CRD"},"date":{"0":"2016-07-01"},"time":{"0":"09:56:00"},"carrierEvent":"Closed \/ carded"}
]
```

I've used [this](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/) to format my Ajax request. Also, is it possible to return the JSON from the Ajax request and parse it via PHP?

How do I go through these and write them all out?

Comment: you're putting the parsed json into `data`, then looking for `data['json']`, but your posted json sample has no `json` key. your json is an array of objects, so you'd have `data[0]` -> `data[2]`, but not `data[json]`

Comment: OK so when I do something like `console.log(data[0]["code"][0]);` that gives me the right output - but how to I loop through them?

Comment: forget json. it's a transport format. jquery already decoded it for you, and you just have a plain old javascript data structure. you parse/loop it like you would any other javascript structure: it's an array, treat it like one.

Comment: Being a noob here but why does'nt `console.log(data.length)` return the number of items?

Comment: it should, unless something weird is going on. what does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: `console.log(data.length): undefined`
`console.log(data): [object Object]`

Comment: Is there any way I can get this array back in PHP and work via PHP on it?

Comment: `lenght != length`. dyslexic moment?

Comment: sorry, the print has a typo, the actual method doesn't - it's spelled right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you are already getting the JSON encoded `data`, hence you can directly iterate through the response using the following code

```
...

success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
      alert(value.code[0] + '---' + value.date[0]); //and so on
    });
}

...
```

> **About Parsing via PHP**

It seems you are already parsing the array in PHP an returning the JSON as response. If you have raw JSON data in PHP then you can convert it to an array using `json_decode($data)` and iterate through the array to do whatever you desire to do with the data.